# Keyboard configuration always returns QWERTY on Chrome OS

Tags: android, keyboard, google-chrome-os, chromebook

### Context

In my **android** app, I am trying to detect when the **hardware keyboard** of the Chromebook is an AZERTY.
To do so, based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#keyboard), I use the following field :

`context.getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard`

### Problem

The problem is : even when the input method & the language of the Chromebook is french and the physical keyboard is an AZERTY, it returns `Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY`

Did I miss something or is it an android internal issue ?

---

*Devices informations :*
Chromebook ASUS Notebook C433T
Chrome OS version : 84.0.4147.127

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in input mode named **AZERTY** ,The API returns is [one of three values](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#keyboard):

> KEYBOARD_QWERTY : Device has a hardware qwerty keyboard, whether it's visible to the user or not.

To create a custom keyboard, you could refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method).

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I understand correctly, you are saying that there is no other way to detect a keyboard as an AZERTY one than to create a custom keyboard (even when the physical keyboard of the chromebook is an AZERTY) ?

Comment: I don't understand the "create a custom keyboard". You don't always deal with soft keyboards (like most of the SO posts tend to look like). Sometimes people deal with physical keyboards (usb, bluetooth, etc)